# How to count regexp in a string and use that number in replacement?

Tags: regular-expressions, query-replace, match-data

In my LaTeX code I want to replace these strings:

```latex
\left.\left.\left.
\left.\left.
\left.
```

with:

```latex
\left.\left.\left. \mycommand{3}
\left.\left. \mycommand{2}
\left. \mycommand{1}
```

where the argument of the command `\mycommand` is the number of the occurrences of the regexp `"\\left\." in each string.

My question is: can I obtain it by a `query-replace`? I figured out something like:

```el
(query-replace-regexp "\\(\\(:?\\\\left\\.\\)+\\)"
                      `(,(lambda (x y)
                           (let* ((MATCH (match-string 0))
                                  (OCCURRENCES 
                                   (my-count-regexp "\\\\left\\."
                                                    MATCH))
                                  (OCCURRENCES (number-to-string OCCURRENCES)))
                             (concat MATCH "\\myfunction{" OCCURRENCES "}")))))
```

But I didn't find a function (`my-count-regexp` in my code) that returns the occurrences of a regexp in a string.

Also I'm not shure of the `lambda function` syntax.

**Edit.** I found that the following code works, but I'm still searching for something simplier:

```el
(query-replace-regexp "\\(\\(:?\\\\left\\.\\)+\\)"
                      `(,(lambda (x y)
                           (let* ((MATCH (match-string 0))
                                  (OCCURRENCES
                                   (with-temp-buffer
                                     (insert MATCH)
                                     (goto-char (point-min))
                                     (count-matches "\\\\left\\.")))
                                  (MATCH (replace-regexp-in-string "\\\\"
                                                                   "\\\\\\\\" MATCH))

                                  (OCCURRENCES (number-to-string OCCURRENCES)))
                             (concat MATCH "\\\\myfunction{" OCCURRENCES "}")))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not derive the number of occurrences from the length of the match?

```
(let* ((match (match-string 0))
       (occurrences (/ (length match) 6))
       ...)
   ...)
```

Comment: Because the matched string may be more complex (e.g. with some tab/space between the `\left.`s). I really need to count the matched regexp in a string.

Answer (score 1):

I would approach it like this:

```
(goto-char (point-min))
(while (re-search-forward "\\(\\(\\\\left\\.\\)+\\)" nil t)
  (let ((s (match-beginning 0))
    (e (match-end 0))
    (m (match-string 0)))
  (cl--set-buffer-substring  s e
   (format "%s \\mycommand{%s}"
           m
           (count-matches "\\\\left" s e)))
  (goto-char e)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is old, and that it asks if it's possible using query replace (although it does not look like anything has to get replaced), but I would still like to add a simple (straightforward) solution here

```lisp
(goto-char (point-min))
(while (re-search-forward "^\\\\left\\." nil t)
  (let ((count 1)
    (end (line-end-position)))
    (while (re-search-forward "\\\\left\\." end t)
      (cl-incf count))
    (insert (format " \\mycommand{%d}" count))))
```

Because `re-search-forward` does not move point if no match is found, the `\mycommand{n}` is always inserted at the correct position.

The first regexp assumes that the patterns start at the beginning of a line (it includes `^`), but this is not required, in that case, just remove the `^`.